# magento jquery-1.10.2.min blocking other script files

Tags: javascript, magento

Am using magento 1.9.3, i creating custom file called declaration.

In declaration page am adding

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">`

This script blocking some function. Like ajax cart, mouse hover menu expand, ect...

How can i fix this issue.

Comment: maybe the page already includes another version of jQuery(probably the old one)....

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Yes you are right but both jQuery important